# Puppet assign nodes to environments from master?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I'm learning to use Puppet and have successfully setup and connected a master server with 2 nodes.

I've created files for the default `production` environment which is working. I also have a second set of configs called `beta` in my environments folder.

I'd like to assign 1 of my 2 nodes to the beta group via the master server. How would I go about doing this?

*Puppet version 4*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The environment can either be set by the agent's `puppet.conf` config file, the agent's `--environment` command line option, or the master using [an external node classifier (ENC)](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/nodes_external.html), in order of increasing precedence.

1. Run `puppet agent -t --environment beta` to run the agent with a non-default environment.
2. Set `environment = beta` under `[agent]` in `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf` to set the default environment.

Or to configure an ENC to define the environment on the master:

1. Create a script such as `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/node.sh` in any language you like, e.g.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   if [ "$1" = beta.example.com ]; then
     echo "environment: beta"
   else
     echo "environment: production"
   fi
   ```
2. Ensure the script is executable (`chmod +x /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/node.sh`)
3. In the *master's* `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf` under `[master]`, set:

   ```
   node_terminus = exec
   external_nodes = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/node.sh
   ```

When the agent runs, it will retrieve the node information from the master, which runs the node script. The script returns a YAML document (one line in this case) with the environment name. If the environment name is given, then the agent will be forced to use that environment.

The script can be implemented however you see fit - it can perform some sort of query (e.g. against a database), perform some logic against the hostname (the first argument, `$1`), or just be hardcoded.